# Writing an array data into external file

Tags: javascript

I am using this demo 
[pitch detector](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/index.html)
to get the pitch of an input data, what I need is to write that captured data into external file or to make a some kind of sine wave to see the frequency of that data
or even better to see what frequencies I don't need. That demo can't show me the more or less precise pitch of the played string,
I searched a lot but nothing seems to fit me. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the extracted data to a backend service using a `form` or AJAX. You could also store it in *localStorage*, *sessionStorage* or the browsers embedded database like IndexedDb or WebSQL. You could then mine that data in your browser. You could also save the data using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/), although that is not widely supported across browsers.